# How to write test cases for function that calling from html

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

**app.component.html**

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled()"></button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
isDisabled(){

if(count==0) return true;
else return false;
}
```

**app.spec.ts**

```
let spy=(component,'isDisabled').and.callThrough();
component.ngOnInit();
expect(spy).toHaveBennCalled();
```

I am calling `isDisabled()` function from button disabled property to enable or disable that button.
But unable to write test cases for the same.
test cases showing success and no code coverage found.

Comment: So you want to test Angular here??

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to have a property `isDisabled` instead of a function. When `count` changes, you update the property `isDisabled` is updated. This is easier to test and has advantages in terms of change detection.

If `count` is an `@Input`:

```
_count = 0;

@Input() set count(count) {
  this.isDisabled = count === 0;
  this._count = count;
}

get count() {
  return this._count;
}

isDisabled = true;
```